# InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version ANACONDA WINDOWS

Tags: python, keras

My system is windows and I installed anaconda. I am using Spyder.
I run a script in Python that imports keras library but when I run I always get this error:

InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

I try to find answers in internet but I do not understand.

Comment: Check you keras version and your cuda driver version. Make sure they are compatible. I am assuming you are using a newer keras version, but your cuda driver is old

Comment: I isntalled recently the keras. How can I see the versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check cuda version by openning command prompt and typing:

```
nvcc --version
```

You could check Cuda driver version by openning command prompt and typing:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi.exe"
```

To check if your cuda and cuda driver version is compatible, check [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#cuda-application-compatibility) link showing which version is compatible with which.

Checking this and making sure your cuda and driver versions are compatible might solve the problem.

Comment: I do not have folder NVSMI in NVIDIA Corporation. Is it normal? Also besides NVIDIA Corporation folder, I have another folder named NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit, which has the CUDA folder with version 10.2. I see the tensorflow has version 2.1.0 and NVIDIA-SMI has version 0.1.3. What is wrong?

Comment: In the link you suggest the compatibility of CUDA is in Linux. I am working in windows. Is that the problem?

Comment: I get the answer. I had CUDA driver in version 10.2 and I changed to version 10.1, as explained here (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34759). And it works.

Comment: Great, if it was helpful, please upvote or accept my answer